# Symfony2 doctrine datetime object format

Tags: datetime, doctrine-orm

I'm using fixtures load to write to a datetime field of an entity.

Entity:

```
/** @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true) */
protected $date;
```

I use the following method to set the date:

```
    public function setDate($date='')
    {
        $fecha = new \DateTime($date);
        $fecha = $fecha->format('Y-m-d');
        $this->date = $fecha;
    }
```

I only want to use the year, month, day in order to get a sum with a group by dql-query.

When I implement fixtures load I get the following error message:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function `format()` on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdo
>   cs\brel\vendor\doctrine-dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateTimeType.php on line 44

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doctrine's `date`, `time` and `datetime` fields assume that the class property is a \DateTime-instance, not a formatted date-string (the formatting is done via the Type-Mapping in Doctrine DBAL).

You can either create a custom Type (see Doctrine DBAL-documentation) or use a different type (string?).

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I know where to look, and also an alternative solution.